# Android WebView loadDataWithBaseURL not work in Android 4.0.3(api15)

Tags: android, webview, android-webview

I use this code to load picture from drawable to my WebView.

```
String s ="<html><body style='margin: 0; padding: 0'><IMG  width='100%' height='100%' src='picturename'><body><html>";
webview.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_res/drawable/", s, "text/html", "UTF-8", null);
```

And test it's on 2 device.

1.HTC Sensation XE With Beats Audio Z715e (Android 4.0.3(api15))------>Not work

2.ASUS fonepad7 K00Z (Android 4.4.2(api19))--------------------------->Work very well

How to solve it's

**EDIT**

Oh!!! I can solve it's

I'm very stupid.

The problem is in picturename.

In android 4.0.3 need file type (example: "picturename.png") but in android 4.4.2 not need.

It's can use filename without file type (example: "picturename").

Comment: i can solve it's. Please see in my edit.

Answer (score 0):

please try this

```
String s ="<html><body style='margin: 0; padding: 0'><IMG  width='100%' height='100%' src='file:///android_res/drawable/picturename'><body><html>";

webview.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, s, "text/html", "UTF-8", null);
```

Comment: if your file have a extension you should use it as example picturename.png